# changing places in the GIS

Tags: gis, viewer, arcmap

Is there a function that chnages the place of a new entity if it's positioned on the same place as an old one? (Both entities are from the same layer)

Comment: In what language, what program, what galaxy? How about investing a little effort to formulate a clear question if you want free help?

Comment: Sorry!!! - I am using Arc Map and I have a couple of layers all contating many entities.
I am looking for a function that will do the following - if a new entity is supposed to be placed in a certain location and an entity is already there it will place the entity in different location ("X" cm away) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a topology to ensure the points are always disjointed.  If they overlap you will get a topology error.

Geodatabase topology rules and topology error fixes:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm